# JavaScript: format and Unformat Number: Library numbro.js

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to find a way to format and unformat numbers  according to the user local using the library `numbro.js`.

Using this library the format of the number should be like that:

```
var number = 1234;

numbro(number).format() // => 1,234 using the defaultLocal which is 'en-US'
```

But when i want to change the local using:  `numbro.language('fr-FR')` or `culture()` function it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

The methods `numbro.culture` or `numbro.language` is for loading a culture if it is not loaded. But you should not need it.

If the **fr-FR** culture is loaded you just need `numbro.setCulture('fr-FR');`

If not - just include the **/languages/fr-FR.js** script and it will be loaded.

Comment: Thank you for your response. In fact i think the problem that the culture is not loaded, because when i tried to format the number according to the deutsh local 'de-DE' format, it didn't work for me. Do you have an idea how to load languages file js in react ?

Comment: Not sure about react, but it should not be different than the way you load numbro.js. It should not be related to react.

Comment: To import `numbro` i added `import numbro from 'numbro'`. But i didn't find a way to load languages too.

Comment: No idea how to import it. It should come from languages/de-DE.js.

Comment: Hello, I find a solution and i want to share it with you. To use `numbro.js` with react you have only to import it using `import numbro from 'numbro'` and then if you want to change the default language, all you need is to call the function `loadCulturesInNode()` like that `numbro.loadCulturesInNode()` : this function will load all the languages available in the library. Then you can set the local using `numbro.culture('de-DE')`.

Answer (score 0):

(Intended for whoever find this question and is using the v2)

As for numbro v2, the API changed a bit. 
Depending on what you use to build your application, you might need to import localisation files, then to register the language you want to use, then set it.

```
// import the file in the build
const numbroLanguages = require('numbro/dist/languages.min.js');
// Make the language available to numbro
numbro.registerLanguage(numbroLanguages['fr-FR']);
// Use it
numbro.setLanguage('fr-FR');
```

http://numbrojs.com/languages.html